# Testing Rabbitmq ack/nack response

Tags: testing, go, rabbitmq

I would like to test my Rabbitmq implementation. I have a queue and consumer, and I would like to have a third element which listens/sniffs the queue response, so the test will fail in case of queue responds nack or pass in case of it is ack.

Do you know how I could do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try out the [tracing plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html). Note that this plugin should **never** be used in production due to the performance overhead it incurs.